# Cómo puedo limpiar un formulario con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, formularios

Este es mi código actual

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var contact_name = $("#name").val();
        var contact_email = $("#email").val();
        var subject = $("#subject").val();
        var your_phone = $("#phone").val();
        var your_message = $("#message").val();
        $.post("sendmail.php", {
            name: contact_name,
            email: contact_email,
            phone: your_phone,
            subject: subject,
            message: your_message,
        }, function(data, status) {


            document.getElementById('msgmail').innerHTML = data

        })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `reset()` en el success del post

```
$(this)[0].reset();
```

o

```
$('#contactform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: No me funciona yo creo que esta embrujado el código jaja

Comment: Entonces saca del success el `reset()` algo esta pasando que no llega, entonces no puede hacer dicha operación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `reset()` después del callback

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        .....
        $.post("sendmail.php", {
            name: contact_name,
            email: contact_email,
            phone: your_phone,
            subject: subject,
            message: your_message,
        }, function(data, status) {
            document.getElementById('msgmail').innerHTML = data
            // limpiamos el formulario
            $('#contactform').get(0).reset()
        })

    });
```

Comment: Ya lo probre pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar limpiando el valor de cada campo de tu formulario.

```js
$("#name, #email, #subject, #phone, #message").val('');
```